# Calculating mass of a solution

Tags: concentration

I am trying to calculate the mass of a specific volume of glucose 5% solution. I calculated the values for the components of the solution and wanted to seperately calculate the mass of the solution based on it's volume as if just the volume and molarity of the solution are known. But I can't figure out why the mass is not equal in both calculations.

I used the weighted average of the glucose and water molar mass to calculate the molar mass of the solution. As well as other combinations of different molar mass and molarity.

I used both the molarity of the solution as moles of solute per litre of solution and the sum of the number of moles of solute and solvant.

[image]

How do I calculate this correctly?

Comment: The density, g/cm^3, is a property of each, separately. Why are you adding them?? When glucose dissolves in water, the density is somewhere *between* that of water and that of glucose. 100% water has a density ~1.00, 100% glucose, ~1.54 (according to the question), so a 50% solution would be ~1.27 (give or take a bit). You can figiure out what 5% density is.

Comment: Note that volume is not additive during dissolution. Density of solutions is empirical value and cannot be derived from basic principles, nor from densities and ratio of the solute and the solvent. You need to get density of 5% glucose solution to know what volume is 100g = 5 g of glucose + 95 g of water (approx. 95 mL )